# New-AzureReservedIP : No default subscription has been designated

Tags: powershell, azure

I never used Azure PowerShell before, but now I'm running a command to have Azure reserve a static IP address:

> New-AzureReservedIP –ReservedIPName "137.117.11.18" –Label "people-dns-ip" –Location "US West"

And then I'm getting this error: New-AzureReservedIP : No default subscription has been designated.

So, I was trying to figure out what is the  or just set to default... using the command Select-AzureSubscription I can see that The subscription name BizSpark doesn't exist.

Not sure how to print the value of Get-AzureSubscription on the screen, but in my Azure portal is says: SUBSCRIPTION NAME BizSpark

Any idea how to resolve this? or maybe this option is limited for BizSpark users??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To use Azure Powershell at very first you should use

Add-AzureAccount

it will give you a popup where you can login with you azure credentials. this way you will connect to your Azure subscription in Azure Powershell

Comment: While running Add-AzureAccount against a ARM subscription, you may get an error "No subscriptions are associated with the logged in account in Azure Service Management (RDFE)". To get around this, please add yourself as an admin/co-admin.

Answer (score 3):

Need to add your azure account to be able to manage assets:

If for some reason method 1 doesn't work, try method 2.

**Method 1:**

At powershell, run:

```
Add-AzureAccount
```

**Method 2:**

At powershell, run:

```
Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile
```

Sign in to the Windows Azure Management Portal, and then follow the instructions to download your Windows Azure publishing settings.

Again at powershell, run:

```
Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile <mysettings>.publishsettings
```

Replace  with the file name of the publishsettings file that you downloaded in the previous step and correct the path if necessary.

Comment: `Add-AzureAccount` before `Select-AzureSubscription` will suffice. Subscription certificates are no longer required for Powershell. In fact, they are deprecated in ARM-mode.

Comment: i could never make it work just with add-azureaccount maybe that's because i have multiple subscriptions or maybe i'm not using corporate account, but without downloading the certificates it doesn't work for me.

Comment: That's strange. I haven't run into any issues with `Add-AzureAccount` for my Microsoft account that's associated with multiple subscriptions. Perhaps you should submit an issue at https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell?

Comment: maybe it was the powershell version i was using at work. Tried at my home computer now. Seems to be working just with add-azureaccount but i had this problem several times before and every time i had to download the certificate. Never bothered to troubleshoot tho. thanks. I've updated the answer.